# Turtlebot - reuse Turtlebot 1's plates and standoffs for use with Kobuki?

Tags: irobot-create, turtlebot2, turtlebot, create, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Turtlebot 1 with an iRobot Create base, and I'd like to upgrade to the Kobuki base replacing as little as possible.
Whilst the Kobuki plates are hexagonal, they look similar to the originals used by the Create. Has anyone tried, or does anyone know if it is possible to use/adapt the Turtlebot 1 plates and standoffs to be used with the new Kobuki base instead?
It would be excellent if this was possible to provide a cheap upgrade path.

Thanks,
Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61588/turtlebot---reuse-turtlebot-1%27s-plates-and-standoffs-for-use-with-kobuki?/) by [MarkStodden](https://answers.ros.org/users/1800/markstodden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-26**:
To the best of my knowledge that should be possible as the turtlebot is standardized. I've never tried it though. You could actually check that quite simply by looking at the hole pattern of the Kobuki base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The upper plates are compatible (same holes plus a few), but its the bottom plate which will cause you problems.

The kobuki and create base are significantly different and because of the hardware, you can only place mounting holes at points which fit with the design and also take advantage of the strongest possible points (otherwise your whole stack becomes unstable).

So, long story short - the kobuki stacks are backwards compatible - we even put in holes so you can reverse the base kobuki plate and use it on a create, but of course, create stacks could not predit forwards compatibility.

Bill at IHR may be the best person to talk to about filling your need, or alternatively get someone to cut your own bottom plate according to the mechanical drawings which are open - you can put your create plates on top of them.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1